# Replacing all the '\' chars to '/' with C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

How can I replace all the '\' chars in a string into '/' with C#?
For example, I need to make @"c:/abc/def" from @"c:\abc\def".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) function seems suitable:

```
string input = @"c:\abc\def";
string result = input.Replace(@"\", "/");
```

And be careful with a common gotcha:

Due to string immutability in .NET this function doesn't modify the string instance you are invoking it on => it returns the result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the \

```
mystring.Replace("\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var replaced = originalStr.Replace( "\\", "/" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var origString = origString.Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string first = @"c:/abc/def";
string sec = first.Replace("/","\\");
```

Comment: oops, I misread 'from' and 'to'.  Just switch the arguments and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
@"C:\abc\def\".Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = @"c:\asb\def".Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
```