# Adding a character into a string after a specific character

Tags: c#

In order to be able to read a file in asp.net, the file path must be written in this:
1.

```
C:\\yung\\Desktop
```

returns
however, the string that the fileUpload get returns is 
2.

```
C:\yung\Desktop
```

After reading the comments i have this code:

```
        string FilePath = FileUploadPublicInfo.PostedFile.FileName;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath);
        string line = File.ReadLines(FilePath.ToString()).Skip(4).ToString();

        TextBox1.Text = line.ToString();
```

But now its giving this error:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<SkipIterator>d__30`1[System.String]
```

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034297/replacing-all-the-chars-to-with-c-sharp might be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure I understand the question, but I think you are looking for `string.Replace`:

```
string DoubleSlash(string singleSlash)
{
    return singleSlash.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
}
```

Comment: @LanYungLee you've tried it, and..? What was wrong? Why does it not answer you question?

Comment: I press wrong, i meant to say that there was another problem.

Comment: Btw the above code, that i added would not require replacing "\" with "\\"

Answer (score 1):

The reason backslashes disappear is that C# compiler treats slashes in string literals as a special "escape" character. Because of this treatment, backslash needs to be encoded as two slashes in a regular string literal.

C# offers two ways of inserting backslashes the way you need:

- **Use verbatim literals** - prefix it with "at" sign, i.e. `@"C:\\yung\\Desktop"`, or
- **Double each slash** - put two slashes for each slash in the result: `C:\\\\yung\\\\Desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have manage to solve this problem, turns out it was not reading anything.

This is the code that i finally get:

This is to retrieve the File's path, using this, would give the file path will double slash, so there is not a need for Replace(@"\",@"\")

```
string FilePath = FileUploadPublicInfo.PostedFile.FileName;
```

Then read the specified file

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath);
```

If you know which line you specifically want, this retrieves the 5th line

```
string line = File.ReadLines(FilePath.ToString()).Skip(4).First().ToString();
```

Thank you so much for your help...